# Css fill div height with color

Tags: html, css, colors

Hey guys I'm having troubles setting a div to fill the whole web with X color (with no height, it has a 30% of widht and I want to fill the rest of the web) , here's the example :

http://gyazo.com/a074f0c6f86dc2a001aba53c672da03c , the div on the left is the one I want to fill vertically the web with that color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following may get you started in the right direction.

In this example, set the height to 100% for the `html` and `body` tags, and then 100% for the left hand panel/div.

I floated the two `div`'s to get the two columns, but there are other ways of creating a two-column layout.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}
.right {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">The left panel.</div>
<div class="right">The right panel.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
}

.left {
    background: #00C5FA;
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 30%;
}


<div class="left block">Hi hi hi!</div>
<div class="right block">Goodbye goodbye!</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/274t6w06/